# How do I format my old hard drive and use a new one?

Tags: windows-7

I have two OS's on my laptop on two different hard drives, the old OS system has all my data on it and it's infected. How do I get rid of the old OS and use the new one on the new hard drive without loosing my data? Please assist.

Comment: Are you looking to also recover the OS on the infected drive, or just your data?

Answer (score 0):

You should get your hard drive (the old one) out of your laptop. Then you connect it to your laptop with an external USB reader and take all the data off of it. That should allow you to a) get all your data off the disk and b) format it if needed and do a fresh install of the OS.

Comment: after you connect it via USB you should scan it with dependable antivirus like malwarebytes and/or avira, norton antivirus etc